# Laravel migration assigns 2 primary key in a table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am having a problem with laravel migration, i have tqo interger in my laravel migration file,
when i try to migrate it reports me error saying that the migration contains 2 primary key.
Does anyone have any idea about this. help would be appreciated.

```
<?php    
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;    
    class CreateLoginTable extends Migration {    
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up(){
            Schema::create('login', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->engine ='InnoDB';
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string ('email', 255);
                $table->string ('username', 255);
                $table->string ('password', 255);
                $table->string ('password_temp', 255);
                $table->string ('code', 255);
                $table->integer ('active', 11);
                $table->timestamps();               
            });
        }    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::drop('login');
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Try `Schema::create('login', function($table){`

Comment: no, does not work for me!!! Any more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Integer columns are called without length (not like in pure mysql). So just call it like:

```
$table->integer ('active');
```

and it will work. Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns